# How to emulate google drive localy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm building a website using gae which will connect to the google drive api.

I would like to emulate the drive functionality(without authentication) locally for testing purposes.

My plan was to create a DriveObject class which defines an interface for accessing drive files.  I would then create two subclasses.  One which connects to the drive api and another that works on the local file system.

Sadly I've found that the gae dev server doesn't have access to the local file system.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: You could the [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) as a "filesystem". Store a JSON object of directories, files, file properties, then have your "local filesystem" class read this.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that looks promising,  I'll give it a go.

Comment: Sadly that's not going to work as I need access to these files on the 'server' side.

Comment: I think I'm going to do this by using the datastore/blobstore it's a more complicated solution than I hoped for but it will work.  I'd still be interested to hear how other people would solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Write an abstraction layer on the top of the Drive API. Provide two implementation: a service layer that uses Drive API and a mock service that acts like it.

Comment: That's not a very helpful answer, If you read the entire question you'll see that I've already proposed an abstraction layer but was looking for advise on how to implement the 'mock service' since I can't access the local file system.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the file system as a Drive API mock? The feature parity btw a file system and the Drive API is kinda low -- depends on which Drive features you're planning to use. Writing blobs to a db would be another option.

Comment: I only need to store and read files and folders.  So the local file system would be fine.  As I commented above I'm currently using the datastore/blobstore which is fine but more complicated than just making files.

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look at service accounts, if user auth flow is too complicated to implement for you initially. For service accounts, you basically download a private key and client libs can retrieve an access token with a single call. Details are on https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts Trivial to implement -- more trivial than reinventing Google Drive for your file system :)

Comment: The problem was never authentication.  The problem was that I wanted to be able to test functionality in the dev server without a connection to the drive servers. Since I only required basic functions from drive (read and write files and folders) which could be easily handled on the file system that was my first plan.  Anyway, in the time since my first post I have implemented all the functions I need both emulated on the datastore and on drive.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rvabdn , is your mock implementation available somewhere?